# Navigating in folders in Total Commander using parts of path

Tags: total-commander

My current dir is

```
c:\projects2016\[projectname].
```

I want to navigate to

```
c:\projects2014\[projectname]
```

with one click or keyboard shortcut. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One click + keyboard shortcut solution:

1. Install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).
2. Create a following `.ahk script (to load automatically, add it to Task Scheduler), to create a hotkey:

```
; ##########     AutoHotKey symbols:                               ##########
; ##########     ! - Alt;   ^ - Ctrl;   + - Shift;   # - Win       ##########
; ##########     Shift + Win + p  =  +#p   (order doesn't matter)  ##########

+#p::

    ; Select all
    SendInput, ^a

    ; Copy the select text to the Clipboard.
    SendInput, ^c

    ; Wait for the Clipboard to fill.
    ClipWait

    ; Perform the RegEx find and replace operation,
    ; where "\projects2016\" is the whole-word we want to replace.
    ; (backslashes need to be escaped)
    haystack := Clipboard
    needle := "\\projects2016\\"
    replacement := "\projects2014\"
    Clipboard := RegExReplace(haystack, needle, replacement)
    ClipWait

    ; Send (paste) the contents of the new Clipboard.
    SendInput, %Clipboard%

    ; Automatically confirm / change to the new dir
    SendInput, {Enter}

return
```

3. When the script is active (green "H" icon in systray) and inside your `c:\projects2016\[projectname]` folder, click on the folder path.
4. Press <kbd>Shift + Win + p</kbd>.

You'll be automatically redirected to your `c:\projects2014\[projectname]` folder. If you need to retain the contents of the clipboard, you need to assign it to a variable first, then paste it back into clipboard at the end of the script.